# Sending info to Server but information is getting lost somewhere

Tags: php, android, sql

I'm calling this code in an android app:

```
public static void sendAccelerationData(String userIDArg, String dateArg, String timeArg,
            String timeStamp, String lat, String longi, String alt)
    {
        //fileName = "AddAccelerationData.php";

        //Add data to be send.
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(6);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userID", userIDArg));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date",dateArg));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("time",timeArg));
        //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("timeStamp",timeStamp));

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat",lat));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longi",longi));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("alt",alt));

        //this.sendData(nameValuePairs);
        try
        {
            TextLog.addLogStuff("SERV Trying to connect to Server");
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new      
            HttpPost("http://myserver.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            Log.i("ServerConn", response.getStatusLine().toString());
            TextLog.addLogStuff("SERV PostData:  "  +response.getStatusLine().toString());
                //Could do something better with response.
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error:  "+e.toString());
            TextLog.addLogStuff("SERV Connection error:  " +e.toString());
        }  
    }
```

Then the code for myserver.php is:

```
  ?php


    //from the online tutorial:

    $usr = "bikemap";
      $pwd = "pedalhard";
      $db = "test";
      $host = "localhost";

      $cid = mysql_connect($host,$usr,$pwd);

      if (!$cid) { echo("ERROR: " . mysql_error() . "\n"); }

      $userID = $_POST['userID'];
      $date = $_POST['date'];
      $time = $_POST['time'];

      $lat = $_POST['lat'];
      $long = $_POST['longi'];
      $alt = $_POST['alt'];
       mysql_select_db("test");
      mysql_query("INSERT INTO gpsdata (userID, date, time, lat, longi, alt) VALUES ('$userID', '$date', '$time', '$lat','$longi','$alt') ") or die(mysql_error()); 

      /*$SQL = " INSERT INTO gpsdata ";
    $SQL = $SQL . " (userID, date, time, lat, longi, alt) VALUES ";
    $SQL = $SQL . " ('$userID', '$date', '$time', '$lat','$longi','$alt') ";
    $result = mysql_query("$SQL");

    if (!$result) {
        echo("ERROR: " . mysql_error() . "\n$SQL\n"); } */

    //echo ("New Link Added\n");



    mysql_close($cid); 
    ?>
```

Somehow the information isn't making it to the sql server.  To just get the methods started I'm passing 6 strings over and over to troubleshoot.  None of which are getting to the server.  Any thoughts?

Edit:

This morning I tried more troubleshooting.  I inserted these lines into my android code:

```
Log.i("ServerConn", response.getStatusLine().toString());
            TextLog.addLogStuff("SERV PostData:  "  +response.getStatusLine().toString());
            TextLog.addLogStuff("SERV rawData:  "  + nameValuePairs);
```

I got this back from the text file created by TextLog:

```
11/11/2011 10:11:09:460 AM:  SERV userID:  Loren 
11/11/2011 10:11:09:464 AM:  SERV Trying to connect to Server 
11/11/2011 10:11:11:666 AM:  SERV PostData:  HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
11/11/2011 10:11:11:674 AM:  SERV rawData:  [userID=Loren, date=today, time=now,
    > lat=bit 1, longi=bit 2, alt=bit 3]
```

So there must be something wrong either with the webpage or the server, right?  More to come.

Edit v2:

I added this to the php file:

```
$string = "User ID:  ";
$string = $string . $userID;
$string = $string . "Date:  " . $date;
$string = $string . "\n";


 $filename = 'test.txt';
 $fp = fopen($filename, "a");
 $write = fputs($fp, $string);
 fclose($fp);
```

And this is the contents of the text file:

User ID:  Date:
User ID:  Date:
User ID:  Date:
User ID:  Date:
User ID:  Date:
User ID:  Date:
User ID:  Date:
User ID:  Date:
User ID:  Date:
User ID:  Date:
User ID:  Date:
User ID:  Date:
User ID:  Date:
User ID:  Date:
User ID:  Date:
User ID:  Date:
User ID:  Date:
User ID:  Date:

Question 1  Am I using the right verbiage to write to the text file?  I answered this earlier today.  I am using the right verbiage.

Question 2  If I am using the right verbiage where is the data from the droid to the page getting lost?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Tested it, everything works fine. So the problem is not in the code. What is the output of Log.i("ServerConn", response.getStatusLine().toString());? Are you sure that the problem is in the android part? Have you tested the PHP script with the browser? Are there any error messages?

Comment: @matthias thanks, I inserted a log to ensure that the strings are being parsed into th e send data method correctly.  The server response has returned http 200 ok.  I also added a text output on the server side that didn't output anything.  So somewhere in android something is getting lost.

Comment: I created a page to post to the server and when I push the post button everything works as it should on the server end.  I am completely stumped.  I am calling the post method every time that the gps position updates.  Is calling that often going to be problematic?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have included the below in your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```